# Minimize and maximize the product of the sum of an nCk combination of an array, with the sum of the remaining items

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

Say you are given an array of signed integers called `NUMBERS` of length `l`. Say `NUMBERS` is equal to

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

where `l = 5`.

You want to form a sum `X` of any `m` elements of the set `NUMBERS` and multiply this by the sum `Y` of the remaining `n` elements for any given `m`, to get a result `X * Y`

This result is thus of the form:

`(x1 + x2 + x3 +...+ xm) * (y1 + y2 +...+ yn)`

where the `xi`s are the elements of the `NUMBERS` array in the `X` sum, and the `yi`s are the elements of the `NUMBERS` array in the `Y` sum.

To be clear:

- `l = m + n`
- `sum(NUMBERS) = sum(X) + sum(Y)`

For example, with `n = 2`, one way to build a result would have `X` be the sum of the elements `1` and `4`, and thus the sum `Y` of the remaining `m = 3` elements be `2 + 3 + 5`. So we would have `X = 5` and `Y = 10` The result would then be the product `X * Y = 5 * 10 = 50`.

We want to find the most efficient way to maximize and minimize this result for a given `m`.

The naive approach would be to try all possible combinations for `X`, and return the result where `(sum(NUMBERS) - sum(X)) * sum(X)` is minimized and maximized. This is of complexity `O(lCn)`.

---

Formally:

Given `(n + m)` signed integers, we want to minimize and maximize the result of the algebraic expression of the form:

`(x1 + x2 + x3 +...+ xn) * (y1 + y2 +...+ ym)`

for a fixed given `n`.

---

I have noticed a pattern where the minimum can usually be obtained by segregating the `m` smallest elements into `X` and the remaining larger elements into `Y`, and the maximum can usually be obtained by evenly distributing the smallest and largest elements in `X` and `Y`. Is there any rationale behind this, or any way to prove this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 3):

Consider a continuous version of the problem where you have a given length $L$ to split into two parts, and you want to maximize their product. In other words, the problem is to find the maximum of $x(L-x)$; the solution is $x=L/2$. (One way to see this is that $x(L-x)$ describes a parabola whose vertex is at $x=L/2$.)

In your case, you want to choose elements from the set that get as close as possible to this even distribution.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a special case of the [AM GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). Simply put, it will always be the case that $\frac{X+Y}{2} \geq \sqrt{X \cdot Y}$. For your application, You already know that $\frac{X+Y}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$ since this is the closed form of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$. So, any partition that sets the sum of the numbers in $X$ equal to the sum of the numbers in $Y$ will work (e.g. place every other element in $X$).